# Не парсится текст

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Вот есть такой текст:

```
<playerWins>
        <playerWin>
            <bossId>1</bossId>
            <droppedKeys>31</droppedKeys>
            <winCount>868</winCount>
            <lastAttack>1380887835</lastAttack>
            <coolWinCount>0</coolWinCount>
            <epicWinCount>0</epicWinCount>
        </playerWin>
        <playerWin>
            <bossId>2</bossId>
            <droppedKeys>99</droppedKeys>
            <winCount>267</winCount>
            <lastAttack>1380857012</lastAttack>
            <coolWinCount>0</coolWinCount>
            <epicWinCount>0</epicWinCount>
        </playerWin>
    </playerWins>
```

Вот так пытаюсь парсить:

```
$getpw = 'Полученный текст проверенно он есть';
preg_match_all("/<playerWin><bossId>1<\/bossId>(.*?)<\/playerWin>/",$getpw,$idpw);
echo $idpw[1][0];
```

Ни чего не показывает.

Comment: Наверно потому, что между `<playerWin>` и `<bossId>` есть переносы строк. И в других местах тоже, что не учитывает регулярка.

Comment: А что изменить нужно?

Comment: Всем спасибо, тема закрыта просто в начале удалил пробелы и отступы  (preg_replace('/\s/', '', $getpw)) и потом начал парсить

Answer (score 4):

Как-то так:

```
    <?php
$str = "<playerWins>
        <playerWin>
            <bossId>1</bossId>
            <droppedKeys>31</droppedKeys>
            <winCount>868</winCount>
            <lastAttack>1380887835</lastAttack>
            <coolWinCount>0</coolWinCount>
            <epicWinCount>0</epicWinCount>
        </playerWin>
        <playerWin>
            <bossId>2</bossId>
            <droppedKeys>99</droppedKeys>
            <winCount>267</winCount>
            <lastAttack>1380857012</lastAttack>
            <coolWinCount>0</coolWinCount>
            <epicWinCount>0</epicWinCount>
        </playerWin>
    </playerWins>";
$players = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
foreach ($players->playerWin as $player){
            var_dump($player->bossId);
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно , так сказать доработать мой метод. Точнее объяснить где что не так.

Comment: непроьблема у вас там отступы и переводы строк, значит как минимум здесь: <playerWin>(должны быть чтото типа звездочки)<bossId> и в конце /playerWin>/ должны быть модификаторы типа is

Comment: Вот так: /<playerWin>*<bossId>1<\/bossId>(.*?)<\/playerWin>/IS

Всё равно что-то не выходит.

Comment: /<playerWin>.?<bossId>1<\/bossId>(.?)<\/playerWin>/is

Вы читаете что там разделитель нужен?

Comment: Всё равно что-то не выходит.

Comment: почему за вас должны все разжевать и в рот положить? Вам же сказали конкретно что между <playerWin> и <bossId> есть символы кроме того есть еще и перенос строки. Значит надо пользоваться /m модификатором как сказал @KryDos , кроме того можно еще добавить is но это как вам будет угодно. Кроме того надо между этими тегами эти символы учесть, в общем если хотите пользоваться регурярками учитивайте все варианты

Answer (score 1):

Реализация через SimpleXMLElement, как посоветовал [@binliz](/users/8664/binliz) выглядит гораздо лучше регулярки в данном случае. Но раз уж Вы хотите улучшать Ваш вариант и есть предположение что у Вас отступы между строками то могу посоветовать передать в регулярку модификатор **m** (PCRE_MULTILINE)

Благодаря этому модификатору текст, в котором Вы что-то ищите будет представлен для регулрки в одну стоку.

```
preg_match_all("/<playerWin><bossId>1<\/bossId>(.*?)<\/playerWin>/m",$getpw,$idpw)
```

Comment: Всё равно что-то не выходит.